# Is there a way to wipe out all of app's alarmmanager alarms without knowing the pending intent ids

Tags: android

In my app I set reminders in AlarmManager and as far as I know, in order to cancel an alarm, I need to remember the unique ID I gave to the pending intent that created the alarm.

Is there a way to generally cancel all of my app's alarms without having to remember that ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From doc [AlarmManager.cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent))

**Remove any alarms with a matching Intent. Any alarm, of any type, whose Intent matches this one (as defined by filterEquals(Intent)), will be canceled.**

---

*So use Class name while creating Intent and set it to pending intent. It does not need to use id, it will match the intent and cancel all alarms. Like below code*

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// Create intent with you service class, which will be matched by alarm manager
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourPendingIntentServiceClass.class);
// Set to pending intent
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
// And cancel alarms
try {
    // Cancel all alarm created with YourPendingIntentServiceClass.
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Something went wrong. Alarms did not cancel. " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: I will try this as soon as I can and inform you of the results

Comment: but when the intents are all equal, as far as I know each one overrides the previous one, so thats why those unique IDs are needed?

Comment: That the story when you need to cancel any particular intent. So we pass id too, to identify target intent from all. Here you want to cancel all, so it will match all those intent who created with that service (and it will return list of intents).